# How do i match all characters between a word & next occurance of space in a line using python

Tags: python, regex

Hi I am trying to match a all character between a word and next occurrence of space character. As shown in below example line.

LINE ENTRY::

1. "abcdefg city=abcd id=1234 type=abcd-efg-jkl-mno country=india"
2. "abcdefg city=abcd id=1234 type=abcd-efg country=india"
3. "abcdefg city=abcd id=1234 type=abcd-efg-jkl country=usa"

If you see there are 3 lines, Line1 has type=abcd-efg-jkl-mno and country=india,

Whereas Line3 has type=abcd-efg-jkl and country=usa.

Now if i want to print the entire line where city=usa and country=usa, how can this be achieved using python regular expressions.

I am trying using match as below.

```
reg1=re.compile('\w+\s+city=+\w+\s+id=+\d+\s+type=+.*+\s+country=+(%s)'%(country_name),re.I)
```

where country_name is the variable to which i am passing the input.

So as soon it encounters ".*" it gives me a **repeat error**. Otherwise it works fine. That is i need to be able to match something like "abcd-efg-jkl-mno" after "type=". But this keeps varying.

That is sometimes "type=abcd-efg-jkl"
Sometimes it will be "type"abcd-efg" or just "type=abcd"

But after "type=+.*" It doesn't check any further. I need to be able to match any character from "type=country=".
Please advise

Answer (score 1):

The `re.split` method can break apart a string on word starts:

```
re.split('\W+', 'Words, words, words.')
['Words', 'words', 'words', '']
```

Then iterate through the list, find the variable name, mod value, etc

*UPDATE:*  [if re.match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match)

```
for entry in lines:
    for var in re.split(" ", entry):
            (field, value) = re.split('=', var)
            # check if value is None, which will be first var of single abcd...)
            if field == 'country': # ("and value == 'usa'" can also be used here)
                value = "new_country"
                # and other fun stuff
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. 

So if i want to make a conditional statement.

By creating a list called entry as you mentioned.

And compare the 5th element "entry[4] with the "country_name" variable. 

How should i do it? 

Will the following syntax work.

if entry[4] == "country="country_name:

Because entry[4] value would be "country=usa"

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is a bit wrong. `.` is followed by a `*` and a `+`. So it throws `sre_constants.error: multiple repeat`.

Change

```
reg1=re.compile('\w+\s+city=+\w+\s+id=+\d+\s+type=+.*+\s+country=+(%s)'%(country_name),re.I)
```

To

```
reg1=re.compile('\w+\s+city=+\w+\s+id=+\d+\s+type=+.*\s+country=+(%s)'%(country_name),re.I)
```

Comment: Thank you :) This worked exactly as i expected the result